# asynchronous callback in mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, mocha.js

The following code doesn't seem right to me, and can probably be written in a nicer way.

For asynchronous tests, mocha needs a callback to be called, namely: done();

Here is my "before" in a mocha test case:

```
before(function (done) {
    get_open_db("./test/test.db")
    get_do_check_db(function() {
        done()
    })
})
```

In the actual segment of code, I added a parameter to do_check_db, namely: cb() in order for the done callback to work.

```
function do_check_db(cb) {
        check_database(function(db_dates) {
            var most_recent_date = db_dates[0]["row.date_id"]
            var least_recent_date = db_dates[db_dates.length - 1]["row.date_id"]
            set_useful_dates(helpers.UsefulDates(most_recent_date, least_recent_date))
            console.log(get_useful_dates())
            if (most_recent_date != useful_dates.today_str ) {
                console.log(("Datebase not recent! Data being used is from: " + most_recent_date).red)
            } else {
                console.log("Database running with latest data!".green)
                most_recent_date = undefined
            }
            cb && cb()
        })
}
```

This seems to be working well, but, is there anyway to prevent adding a callback to the function? I've only added cb for mocha to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_do_check_db` function *is* asynchronous, so it would only make sense it would need a callback. How else would Mocha (or anything else) know the function finished? If you don't care that it is actually finished *before* your first test is run, just call done directly afterward (or don't supply the done parameter at all).

```
before(function (done) {
    get_open_db("./test/test.db")
    get_do_check_db();
    done();
})
```

But I suspect you want `get_do_check_db` to finish before the first test is run, in which case what you have is perfectly appropriate.